# Counterexample of polynomials in infinite dimensional Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I'm trying to prove exercise I.3.B in Mujica's "Complex analysis in Banach spaces".

DEFINITIONS:

> A map $P$ is an m-homogeneous polynomial from $E$ to $F$ if there is a m-linear map $A$ from $E^m$ to $F$ such that $P(x)=A(x, \dots, x)$.
>
> $P$ is a polynomial of degree at most $m$ if $P = P_0 + \dots + P_m$ where each $P_j$ is an j-homogeneous polynomial.

I have to find a function $f: E \to \mathbb{K}$ (where $E$ is infinite dimensional) such that $f(a + \lambda b)$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$ for all $a,b \in E$ but $f$ is not a polynomial.

$f$ clearly has to be discontinuous because there is a theorem implying that $f$ would be a polynomial in the continuous case.

I thought about considering something like (where $\theta$ stands for the step function):

$$f(a+\lambda b) = \theta (\| b\| -1) (a_1 + \lambda b_1)$$

But I don't know how to prove that $f$ wouldn't be a polynomial or even how to apply it to an arbitrary $x \in E$.

I also know that the restriction of $f$ to any finite dimensional subspace of $E$ is indeed a polynomial and that there is a sequence of homogeneous polynomials $P_k$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} P_k(x)$ where for each $x \in E$ $P_k(x)=0$ for all but finitely many indices.

What function could act as a good example for this situation?

I can provide any definition if you're not familiar with the terminology. Please ask for clarification in a comment if that is the case.

Comment: Unless $E$ is a Banach algebra (as opposed to a Banach space), I don't see how $f$ could be a polynomial, as we would need to have vector multiplication defined. So, I must be missing something here.

Comment: @anonymous Yes, I'll add the definition of polynomial between Banach spaces to the question. I hope it will be clear then.

Comment: Are you sure the definition says linear and not multilinear or $m$-linear?

Comment: @Justpassingby Yes, that's a typo. A is m-linear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{x_i;i\in I\}$ be a Hamel basis for $E.$ If $E$ is infinite dimensional then without loss of generality we can have $I$ include the natural numbers as a subset.

Define

$$f:E\to\mathbb K:\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_ix_i\mapsto\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\alpha_n^n.$$

Then $f$ cannot be a polynomial of degree at most $m$ for any $m,$ because for all $\lambda\in\mathbb K$ we have

$$f(\lambda x_{m+1})=\lambda^{m+1}$$

On the other hand for fixed $a$ and $b$ in $E$ the function $\lambda\mapsto f(a +\lambda b)$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$ because $a$ and $b$ are linear combinations of a finite number of elements from the Hamel basis.