# Polynomials in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a complex infinite-dimensional Banach space, and $f:X \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ is a continuous map. Call $f$ a formal polynomial if $f(a+zb)$ is a polynomial in $z$ for each pair of $a,b \in X$; Call $f$ a genuine polynomial if there exists a finite $k$ such that $$f(h)=\sum_{n=0}^{k} L_n (\underbrace{h,h,...,h}_{n \text{ times}})$$ where $L_n$ is a continuous symmetric $n$-linear map on $X$ ($L_0$ is defined to be constant).

As stated in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584374/counterexample-of-polynomials-in-infinite-dimensional-banach-spaces), it is a theorem that continuous formal polynomials are equivalent to genuine polynomials, but I'm having trouble illustrating the proof from "formal" to "genuine": I was stuck at controlling the degree of a formal polynomial by its continuity, which plays an important role in determining the finiteness of that polynomial.  Could it relate to Fréchet derivatives? Any hint or reference is welcome.